# Strategy with Internet connection retrying

Tags: android, networking

In my Android application I have `IntentService` which is uploading something.

Sometimes there is no Internet connection or connection quality is too poor to upload. In these cases `service` needs to retry at some point. I have `BroadcastReceiver` which wakes up my `service` when there is a change in network connection or after some time (if there was a connection but upload failed).

What is the best strategy to wake up such `upload service`? When should I wait and how much? Should I always wake up `service` immediately after network change is received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe talks from Google employees, such as Reto Meier, advise to create a system in which re-trying takes longer and longer, by doubling (or some other factor) the idle time.

So first time you wait... 5 seconds, then 10, 20, 40, 80....

Comment: Yes, but what with connection change? For example, if user changes connection type every 5 minutes and connection is always too poor app would ask after 5, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160, 5, 10, 20, 40, and so on, seconds.

Comment: I think it is suppose to reset the retry-rate when a connection is successfully established.